# Assigning a value returned from a SQL command to a variable

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to assign a value returned from a SQL command in visual studio to a variable. 
This will then allow me to have a tiered login system.

My current code is:`

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdLogin.Click
    Dim Con As SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim sqlstring As String
    Dim connstring As String
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim inc As Integer = 0
    Dim userlevel As Integer

    connstring = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Assignment.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"

    Con = New SqlConnection(connstring)
    Con.Open()


    sqlstring = ("SELECT level FROM Users WHERE Id='" & _txtUsername.Text & "' and pass='" & _txtPassword.Text & "'")
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlstring, Con)
    ds = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "Users")


    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        MsgBox("Username Correct. Welcome!")
    Else
        MsgBox("Hackers are not welcome! Shoooo")
    End If


End Sub
```

This works. However I am unsure on how to assign the level to a visual basic variable. Any help greatfully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0
   userlevel = CInt(ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("level"))
```

However, since your query returns a single value, I would use [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of filling the dataset.

Note however that your query is susceptible to Sql Injection attacks. You should replace the bindings with a [parameterized approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2).

Answer (score 1):

You already have it in the table:

```
MessageBox.Show("Level = " & ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("level"))
```

Btw., even though you do not welcome Hackers, Hackers would highly welcome your code.
Read about SQL Injection, and then use parameters.

Try

```
0'; UPDATE Users SET pass='welcomeHackers'; --
```

in the username field.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to return a single data from SQL query, then instead of using SqlDataAdapter and DataSet, you should consider using SqlCommand and then call its ExecuteScalar method to get the value.

Refer MSDN for more info on using ExecuteScalar.

[More info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Hackers are not my concern. This is for a universtiy project i am working on. Glad to see such a concern though! I shall try out the above methods and see what i can do!